# Chromedriver maximize issue

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm new to this forum as well as to programming and selenium.
I'm trying to maximize my chrome browser using selenium python(using the below code) and everytime selenium opens the browser it would not maximize the whole window.It maximizes only half the screen with "data:," already filled on the address bar.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
self.driver.maximize_window()
```

I also tried

```
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

but doesn't help

[image: Screenshot of the browser]

Answer (score 9):

Just looked at my code and noticed that my import is

```
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

And the rest of the code is

```
 options = Options() 
 options.add_argument("--start-maximized") 
 driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

This does work

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=985) in ChromeDriver which is *specific to Mac OS X*.

What I remember helped was to first set the dimensions explicitly and then maximize:

```
driver.set_window_size(1200, 800)
driver.maximize_window()
```